# Way to split a string in Python without using the .split function

Tags: python, string, split

Here is my code:

```
words = firstsentence.split(' ')
```

`firstsentence` is a user input. The variable 'words' stores the word by word separated form of the user input.

For example, if `firstsentence` was "I like to do coding", `.split` would save it as a list of separated words in the variable `words`.

What I want to know is, is there any way to do exactly what `.split` does but without involving any built-in python functions like `.split`?

It has to separate the words and then store the separated words in a variable.

Comment: must be an assignment (homework). Else why would OP reinvent the wheel? What else is "forbidden"? concatenation? for loops ? BTW your title says: "Way to split a string in Python with using the .split function" which is the opposite. Please care about your asking.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - It is an assignment but, I'm not asking it because of what you think. I think that I would get more marks if I display a way of splitting the string, without using the built in function, btw this is only a small part of a program that i am making, there is more too it, so dont think that my assignment depends on this or anything. :-) (not being rude, genuinely want you to get what i asked the question), and thx just noticed it now

Comment: @StreetSoldier trust me, you'll get lower grade for avoiding such a builtin.

Comment: @StreetSoldier unless your teacher had forbidden you to use it, you should use it. Period. Looks at the answers trying to workaround this by a zillion lines of code or regex. You could use `split` for your assignment, and show a way to do it manually on the side. That would be better.

Comment: @UrielEli@Jean Thx for the advice everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
words = []
current_word = ""
for char in firstsentence:
    if char == " ":
        words.append(current_word)
        current_word = ""
    else:
        current_word += char

words.append(current_word)
```

This iterates all the characters and if current character is normal character, it appends it to `current_word`. If, however, current character is space, it appends the word to `words` list and resets the temporary word.

Edit: I fixed the example by adding last line, thanks Tomerikoo.

Comment: Not downvoting: it kinds of answers the question. But don't do that at home: appending to a string is underperformant (even in-place with `+=`). You could have created a list of chars instead, and used `str.join` but oh, if you cannot use `str.split` then you cannot use `str.join` :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre What do you mean by underperformant? So what would the code look like then, if i am allowed to use str.join (i'm allowed to use whatever i want)

Comment: if you're allowed to use `join` you're allowed to use `split` :) That was more a comment for the answerer. I meant that speed is mediocre when appending a string to a string. That's why `join` (amongst other things) is used, with an empty join string. you can use it to recreate a string from a list of chars.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thx for the explanation

Comment: This will miss the last word (Assuming the string doesn't end with a space)... Need to add another `words.append(current_word)` after the loop

Answer (score 0):

It’s really hard to know what counts as a built-in function in the OP, but here is one solution using slicing:

```
start = 0
words = []
for ix, x in enumerate(firstsentence):
    if x == ' ':
        words.append(firstsentence[start:ix])
        start = ix + 1
if start < len(firstsentence):
    words.append(firstsentence[start:])
```