# Appending a char to an empty list

Tags: python

I am very new to programming, so sorry for a basic question. I am trying to write a function that will take a string in which words are divided by ',' and return a list of these words (the Split method). My code is:

```
def str_to_list(my_shop_str):
    
    my_shop_list = ['']
    word_in_list = 0
    for letter in my_shop_str:
        if letter != ',':
            my_shop_list[word_in_list] += letter
        else:
            word_in_list += 1
            my_shop_list + ['']
    return my_shop_list
```

`print(str_to_list("Milk,Cottage,Tomatoes"))` should look like `[Milk, Cottage, Tomatoes]`

but I am keep getting `IndexError: list index out of range.`
I read some answers here and couldn't find something to work.
Can anyone explain what is wrong.

Comment: In case you aren't already aware, [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) is a built-in method.

Comment: You increment `word_in_list` for every *character* that is not a comma, rather than every *word*.  Then when you do `my_shop_list[word_in_list]`, that produces the out-of-bounds error.

Comment: You probably meant `my_shop_list += ['']` and forgot the `=`. Just a typo...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877531/splitting-strings-in-python-without-split ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526283/way-to-split-a-string-in-python-without-using-the-split-function

Comment: Please note that `word_in_list` is not really necessary. You can just do `my_shop_list[-1] += letter`. And it is more idiomatic to do `my_shop_list.append('')` than using addition

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks! that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` has the method [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) so a solution will be something like this:

```
def str_to_list(my_shop_str):
    my_shop_list = ['']
    word_in_list = 0

    for letter in my_shop_str:
        if letter != ',':
            my_shop_list[word_in_list] += letter
        else:
            word_in_list += 1
            my_shop_list.append('')
    return my_shop_list
```

PS: Do not forgot about empty spaces between words in string like `"aaa, bbb, ccc"` will be `['aaa', ' bbb', ' ccc']` with spaces.

Comment: Thank you! Also, what is the clearest way to write the empty space part? I  would guess it needs to be in the "If" line or is it better to use a method to delete all spaces in the first place?

Comment: I think, the best way is to use python build-in function `replace(" ", "")`. In your case before loop you should call `my_shop_str = my_shop_str.replace(" ", "")`. (first argument is what you want to replace and second for what).

Answer (score 0):

```
def sp(s):
    l =[]
    while True:
        comma = s.find(',')
        if comma == -1:
            l.append(s)
            break
        l.append(s[:comma])
        s = s[comma+1:]
    print(l)
```

this is a simplified version hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest Way:**
We can use an inbuilt split function.

```
def Convert(string):
    # split the string whenever "," occurs
    # store the splitted parts in a list
    li = list(string.split(","))
    return li
 
 
# Driver code
str1 = "Hello,World"
print(Convert(str1))
```

Output:
["Hello", "World"]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).